# Car window rollers

Tags: word-request

I know that you would call the image bellow a "window roller"  or a "window hand roller":
[image]

but what would you call when it is electrical? I mean:

[image]

In my language, they are both the same, but in a technical paper, if one needs to technically mention, they would call them "electrical" or "mechanical" window rollers and whereas there is almost no any car using the "hand window rollers" these days, no one mentions it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanical ones are referred to as **"a roll up handle"**, **"a manual hand crank"** or the most popular version **"a window crank"**.

The automatic ones are mostly referred to as **"window switches"**. Like **"driver side window switch**" or **"passenger side window switch"**.

If you are mentioning the mechanism itself then there's *a regulator* and *a motor*. Basically that makes a *Window Regulator Kit with (or without) a motor*. There are also *"window buttons"* that you can inplace into a door.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the overall mechanism itself, one could call them **power windows** or **electric windows**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_window

With respect to the actual switch itself, they are rather unimaginatively named '**power window switches**' or '**power window rocker switches**', there's no special term to describe them. However we still regularly use the anachronism "wind up/down the window" to describe the actual process of raising or lowering the window, regardless of whether they are electric or not.

Comment: I've heard roll up/down to speak of the action!